# FT searching in a view pannel

Tags: full-text-search, xpages

I am try to create a search string to add the view pannel search property. I need to be able to search between 2 dates ( from date and to date). The syntax that works is date equal to e.g. (FIELD Form ="form") AND (FIELD dateCompleted = 01/01/2012) works OK.
The dates are inputed into 2 input controls using a date picker or entered manually. 
If the try 
(FIELD Form ="Form") AND (FIELD dateCompleted => 01/01/2012) AND (FIELD dateCompleted <= 31/01/2012) to search between the 2 dates, I get an error, or seach return no documents found. There are documents (dateCompleted is date/time field), so should return dococuments.
Any idea what the correct syntax should be?

Comment: please provide exact error you get.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(FIELD Form ="form") AND ((FIELD dateCompleted => 01/01/2012) AND (FIELD dateCompleted <= 31/01/2012))
```

Comment: You can use square brackets around the field instead of typing "field"

Comment: like [dateCompleted ] <= 31/01/2012 or dateCompleted <= [31/01/2012] ?

Answer (score 2):

Dates and numbers may be pretty troublesome sometimes with FT - it is full "TEXT" anyway.
In your case, try to switch month and day - 01/31/2012 - this can be very sensitive according to various seting at OS and Domino level.

Comment: The database if full text indexed and I make sure that the ft index is upto date when I try the search

Comment: The database if full text indexed and I make sure that the ft index is upto date when I try the search. I have noticed that a date that I enter into a input text field and save it as Date/Time in document works ok, but I added the dateCompleted field via

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax appears to be fine (although => should probably be >= ). The problem with not being able to search between dates might be caused by an incorrect data type for your dateCompleted field in the database's **UNK table**. The UNK table lists all fields in a database and their datatypes and is used by the FT search. If the field isn't defined as a date field, a "between dates"-fulltext search won't work. AFAIK the first occurrence of a field creates the entry in the UNK table: so if that's an empty field it will think it's a text field.

More information about the UNK table can be read [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21100238). IBM also offers a [tool](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24004373) to view the UNK table. The UNK table is recreated if you issue an compact -c on the database.

Comment: Mark the [too][1] does not appear to be working. Through the document properties it showing as a Date/Time field. It was created by LotusScript using doc.dateCompeted = Today. regrading the UNK table,When you say that if the field is empty, do you mean that if there are 10 document and in one of those documents the dateCompleted field is blank, then in the UNK it will be regarded as text field rather than a date/Time field. I think the field was orginally defined as a Text field, which I changed to Date/Time on the form. The UNK table infor is new to me, send me to a link where I can find more

Comment: I've updated the links. The first occurrence of a field determines the field's data type in the UNK table. If your field first was a text field, it is probably listed as a text field in the UNK table.